Terraform insists on changing ACM cert
I have a Terraform setup that provisions the required resources to serve a web-server hosted on AWS.
When I do not change anything locally within the .tf files and simply input Terraform Plan, Terraform insists on changing the SSL certificate:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following
execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following
symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_acm_certificate.resume-app-cert will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_acm_certificate" "resume-app-cert" {
        id                        = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:**redacted**"
        tags                      = {
            "Name" = "resume-app-ssl-cert"
        }
        # (15 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.

The ACM.tf file looks like this:
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "resume-app-cert" {
  domain_name       = var.domain_name
  validation_method = "DNS"

  subject_alternative_names = [var.wildcard_domain_name]

  tags = {
    Name = var.aws_certificate_name
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "resume-app-cert" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.resume-app-cert.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.cname-validation : record.fqdn]
}

The variables hold these values:
var.domain_name = redacted.com
var.wildcard_domain_name = *.redacted.com

I saw a couple posts on Stack and different places suggesting a fix, but to me it seems like that fix is already implemented in my configuration, more specifically that the SAN shouldn't include the root domain name, such as:
subject_alternative_names = [var.domain_name, var.wildcard_domain_name]

Here's a reference to the supposed fix, that doesn't seem to work for me:
Terraform forces replacement of 'aws_acm_certificate' with multiple 'subject_alternative_names'
Basically I expect that running Terraform Plan without changing anything will not try to replace the SSL cert.

It does not say it is replacing the SSL cert. It says it is updating it in place. Any real change to the certificate would require a replacement, so it isn't making any major change. From the plan output, it strangely doesn't show any change being made at all. Maybe it's just the tag that is being updated.

I think it may just be updating the Terraform state. Is there anything in the terraform plan output above that, saying it detected changes in that resource that occurred outside of Terraform? Also, are you using the latest version of Terraform, and the Terraform AWS provider?

This smells like a bug in the hashicorp/aws provider's implementation of aws_acm_certificate; it seems to be returning something confusing from the request to plan changes to this object which Terraform Core recognizes as requesting an update-in-place but the UI doesn't know how to describe it as a diff. I'd suggest opening a bug report about it.

I managed to resolve this, there are 2 things that I believe solved this:

Updating Terraform. I was running 1.5.7 and upgraded to 1.8.5
Following this thread: Terraform forces replacement of 'aws_acm_certificate' with multiple 'subject_alternative_names'

This isn't necessarily the desired behavior, but now when I run tf plan I get:
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

